# How to install the latest version of PHP 5.4 on Debian 8 (Jessie)?

Tags: php, debian

I'm trying to install PHP on Debian 8 for a project I'm working on. The project requires PHP 5.4 and can't any of the later versions of PHP (5.5 and 5.6). Whenever I install php5 using apt-get, it installs the latest available version of PHP 5.6. How do I install PHP 5.4.44 (or whatever the latest version of PHP 5.4 actuall is)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the old stable (wheezy) repos to the apt sources lists.
Create a file at:

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/wheezy.list

And add following content:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

run following commands to update the repo infos and install php5.4.44

```bash
apt-get update
apt-get install php5=5.4.44-0+deb7u1
```

You should think about version pinning. You could do that similar to:

Create a file at:

/etc/apt/preferences.d/php5

```
Package: php5*
Pin: release a=oldstable
Pin-Priority: 700

Package: php-*
Pin: release a=oldstable
Pin-Priority: 700
```

Edit:
The version of PHP5.4 has been updated to 5.4.45 so you may do a version lookup before installing this specific version and just replace the version number with the newest.

Answer (score 1):

The distribution has had an update since then. As of today, the version has been bumped so try:

```bash
apt-get install php5=5.4.45
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `apt-get install` and by adding `=` beside the php5 you can name what the version exactly you want ,Such that if you want to install the version named 5.4.44, you use this:

```bash
apt-get install php5=5.4.44
```

Comment: I keep getting this: `E: Version '5.4.44' for 'php5' was not found`

Comment: you have to ckeck it by typing : apt-cache policy php5 and see if it exist in the list